# Add download Button for React Table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to add a download button that downloads a dynamic react table on click as a csv File but I'm not sure how to do it..

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import DynamicTable from '@atlaskit/dynamic-table';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const Wrapper = styled.div`
min-width: 600px;
th{font-size:13px}
th{font-size:14px} `;


render() {
const { error, isLoaded, shareFilterRows } = this.state;
if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading Shared Filters...</div>;
} else {
  return (<Wrapper>
    <div>
    <DynamicTable
      head={shareFilterHead}
      rows={shareFilterRows}
      rowsPerPage={10}
      defaultPage={1}
      loadingSpinnerSize="large"
      isLoading={false}
      isFixedSize
      defaultSortKey="filterID"
      defaultSortOrder="ASC"
      onSort={() => console.log('onSort')}
      onSetPage={() => console.log('onSetPage')}
      
      />
  </div>
  </Wrapper>
  );
  }
}
```

}

This is how my table gets displayed [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QXnj.png). I would appreciate any hint or help to make that button work. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table in that library does not look like I can do exporting natively. So you would need to get the data from your `shareFilterRows` and `shareFilterHead`, convert it back to json or take the parent `data` json and convert it to a csv on your own. There are some libraries out there like [react-json-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-to-csv)